# How i do subroutes with nested components

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

What is the right way to setup components if your app has the following routes.

1. **exampleapp.dev** - Home page
2. **exampleapp.dev/dashboard** - Dashboard page with sidebar and main content
3. **exampleapp.dev/dashboard/resource/create** - Same sidebar, different content containing a form to collect data

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Navbar from "./components/layouts/Navbar";
import Home from "./components/pages/Home";
import About from "./components/pages/About";
import Dashboard from "./components/dashboard/Dashboard";
import Footer from "./components/layouts/Footer";

import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className="App">
          <Navbar />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
            <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            {/* 
              Do i do this
              <Route exact path="/dashboard/resource/create" component={Form} />
            */}
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";
import Main from "./Main";

class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div id="sidebar" className="col-md-3">
            <Sidebar />
          </div>
          <div id="main" className="col-md-9">
            <Main />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

When the user goes to **exampleapp.dev/dashboard/resource/create**

I only want to **change the content in the div with the id of main**

I have component that has form.

**Form.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Form extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Form goes in here</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Form;
```

Do i have to create a new component called CreateResource.js and repeat everything in Dashboard.js and just swap out the  with

What is a proper way to do this? Using react-router-dom?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement nested Routing (child routes) in react router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55238776/how-to-implement-nested-routing-child-routes-in-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `nested routes` if you do not make use of `exact` attribute on the top level. Also `Switch` component allows you to only render one `Route` so you can re-order your routes in a way that it the routes with prefix paths to other Routes are at the end

```
<Router>
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </Router>
```

And in the dashboard component you would have

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div id="sidebar" className="col-md-3">
            <Sidebar />
          </div>
          <div id="main" className="col-md-9">
            <Switch>
                 <Route path="/dashboard/resource/create" component={Form} />
                 <Route component={Form} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```